# Out of memory Fatal Exception

Tags: android, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I have an Activity that contains 12 ImageViews. In onCreate method I load 12 photos in these ImageViews using **BitmapFactory.decodeStream(...)**.

When I come to this page and return back for 10 times I get the following Out of Memory Exception.

Why I get this error and how can I release resources to prevent this exception?

Thanks,

```
04-24 14:41:00.050: D/TextView(7586): Constructor - Got appearance for textColorPrimaryInverse
04-24 14:41:00.050: D/TextView(7586): Constructor -- Got mEditTextBackgroundColor
04-24 14:41:00.130: I/dalvikvm-heap(7586): Clamp target GC heap from 48.878MB to 48.000MB
04-24 14:41:00.130: D/dalvikvm(7586): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 495K, 2% free 47950K/48775K, paused 44ms
04-24 14:41:00.130: I/dalvikvm-heap(7586): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 404616-byte allocation
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm-heap(7586): Clamp target GC heap from 48.856MB to 48.000MB
04-24 14:41:00.180: D/dalvikvm(7586): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 23K, 2% free 47926K/48775K, paused 48ms
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/dalvikvm-heap(7586): Out of memory on a 404616-byte allocation.
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a54460 self=0x1ad5828
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   | sysTid=7586 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074742408
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   | schedstat=( 14073874000 2242143000 19299 ) utm=1301 stm=106 core=1
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at org.mabna.order.utils.Utilities.decodeFile(Utilities.java:1220)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at org.mabna.order.businessLayer.db.BoInvProducts.getProductPhoto(BoInvProducts.java:107)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at org.mabna.order.ui.ActProductsGallery.loadPageImages(ActProductsGallery.java:729)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at org.mabna.order.ui.ActProductsGallery.selectItemInGallery(ActProductsGallery.java:611)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at org.mabna.order.ui.ActProductsGallery.onCreate(ActProductsGallery.java:315)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-24 14:41:00.180: I/dalvikvm(7586):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 14:41:00.180: D/skia(7586): --- decoder->decode returned false
04-24 14:41:00.180: D/AndroidRuntime(7586): Shutting down VM
04-24 14:41:00.180: W/dalvikvm(7586): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a531f8)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at org.mabna.order.utils.Utilities.decodeFile(Utilities.java:1220)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at org.mabna.order.businessLayer.db.BoInvProducts.getProductPhoto(BoInvProducts.java:107)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at org.mabna.order.ui.ActProductsGallery.loadPageImages(ActProductsGallery.java:729)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at org.mabna.order.ui.ActProductsGallery.selectItemInGallery(ActProductsGallery.java:611)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at org.mabna.order.ui.ActProductsGallery.onCreate(ActProductsGallery.java:315)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-24 14:41:00.180: E/AndroidRuntime(7586):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 14:41:01.350: I/Process(7586): Sending signal. PID: 7586 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, decode your images with the nearest size of your `ImageViews` (see this : [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966))

Comment: I am using this code now. My problem is releasing the memory when I exit the Activity.

Comment: Have you tried using bitmap.recycle() on all bitmaps when your activity exits ?

Comment: what is this method? can you explain more?

Comment: As far as I know, when you allocate some memory for bitmaps, they won't be released until you implicitly ask for. bitmap.recycle() will erase all memory related to that bitamp.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are switching activities the wrong way and keeping to many instances in memory. You could try setting FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP on the intent that opens this activity or take a look at [Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to figure out where you should load the images.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

1. recycle the bitmaps like this

   ```
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       TermElement e = theFiveGaugesInclRPMInPos4[i];
       e.background.recycle();
       e.background = null;
   }
   if (DEBUG)
       Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), " <<-"
           + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName());
   }
   ```
2. to reuse the bitmap I define it as static and just init like this:

   ```
     if (faceTexture == null)
       faceTexture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
           .getResources(), faceTextureID);
   ```
3. check memory usage with DDMS

Now it doesn't crash anymore.

ps sorry for the formatting - it just doesn't let me format the code correctly anymore - have to reboot? :-(